# sorted linked list insertion

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to create a function that does sorted insertion based on two variables, first `level`(numerically) & `name`(alphabetically).
Apparently I'm having some logic Error.

My linked list structure:

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int level;
    char *name;
};
```

My string compare function:

```
int compare(struct node *one, struct node *two)
{
    return strcmp(one->name, two->name);
}
```

My insertion function:

```
void insert(struct node **head, const int level, char *name, int(*cmp)(struct node *l, struct node *r))
{
    struct node *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof *new);
    new->level = level;
    new->name = name;

    /* Find the insertion point */
    for (; *head != NULL; head = &(*head)->next)
    {
        if ((*head)->level > level) {
            if (cmp(*head, new) > 0)
            break;
        }
    }

    new->next = *head;
    *head = new;
}
```

sample input:

```
insert(&root, 1, "A", compare);
insert(&root, 1, "C", compare);
insert(&root, 1, "B", compare);
insert(&root, 3, "B", compare); 
insert(&root, 2, "Z", compare);
insert(&root, 1, "A", compare);
insert(&root, 1, "C", compare);
insert(&root, 1, "B", compare);
insert(&root, 3, "B", compare);
insert(&root, 2, "Z", compare);
```

result :

```
1       A
1       C
1       B
1       A
3       B
1       C
1       B
2       Z
3       B
2       Z
```

Comment: `if ((*head)->level > level) {` -->> `if ((*head)->level >+ level) {` would probably help a bit. (but I think you need two separate conditions: one to continue, and one to break;)

Comment: @wildplasser What is the significance of the change `>` to `>+` ?

Comment: Oops, that should have been a `>=` On second thought, I would have used one continue plus two separate breaks. I think...

Comment: _My string compare function:_ @pouria has forgotten the code.

Comment: try `if((*head)->level > level || (*head)->level == level && cmp(*head, new) > 0){
            break;
        }`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Exactly. Or: in separate continue break statements, which is less error-prone, IMHO. (resulting code is the same, obviously)

Comment: @wildplasser The results are different. your [result](http://ideone.com/EjY7uJ),  my [result](http://ideone.com/Deys0d)

Comment: I don't care. It is trivial; basically just a composite compare. BTW: the OP just posted the same question (including the compare function) in another question.

Comment: The comparison function has disappeared by the update. (but It was generally expected. I think that it is necessary to ignore the case.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thanks for the suggestion it has solved my logic error. if you like to post it as an answer I would be glad to check it as a correct answer.

Comment: It is too late. :)